# htaccess redirection of a specific page, not whole domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a *page* (not whole domain!) to a specific other page that's on another domain, with htaccess. I tried a couple of things but can't make it to work. Can anybody help me out?

I tried this one:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com/example [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) https://otherdomain.com/page [P]
```

and this one:

```
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com/example/$ [NC,OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com/example/$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mainpage.com/pagename/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

The page that should be redirected is /example

domain.com/example >>> should redirect to: https://otherdomain.com/page

The page that should be directed is accessible with and without www. in front of it, not sure if this is relevant.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and how that doesn't work ?

Comment: I tried this one:

`#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com/example [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*) https://otherdomain.com/page [P]`

Comment: Please do not post your code in the comment section. Post it in your question by clicking the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65072881/edit) link.

Comment: Sorry, edited my first post.

Comment: Do you get any error with your rule and how does it not work?

Comment: No error, just doesn't work :( 
I must add to that that the link does not exist, meaning /example is not a file or page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule doesn't work because it has an error in the `RewriteCond`

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com/example/$ [NC,OR]
```

This condition will never be met as `%{HTTP_HOST}` variabe only contains the host header ie. `example.com` and not the URI string `/example/` .  You can test URI string using `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable in a separate `RewriteCond` .

This should work for you

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /example [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://otherdomain.com/page [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works!! Just wondering, but is this also possible with a redirect while you don't see the url changing?

Comment: @Vincentin This is possible with `P` proxy flag. If proxy module is enebled on your server then simply replace the `[R,L]` with `[P]` in the RewriteRule above. You will get a 500 server error  if the module isn't enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that doesn't work but maybe I can enable the module. Thanks so much! :)